# Sorting MySQL records chronologically?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a bunch of records in a MySQL table, each with a date attribute (m.d.Y), and a time attribute stored as hr:min:sec. I want to sort them chronologically based on both the date and the time. How would I do that with PHP/MySQL?

**Edit**: If you think there's a more efficient way at storing my date and time in the database, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you think there's a more efficient way at storing my date and time in the database, please let me know.

Yes, make a field of `datetime` or `timestamp` in your table, create an index by this field and sort by it.

Queries:

```
/* add a column */
alter table `table` add column `created_at` datetime not null default "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
/* create an index */
alter table `table` add index `created_at` (`created_at`)
/* sort */
select * from `table` order by `created_at`
```

Comment: So how would I exactly store the datetime in the database? Would it just be something like "day.month.year.hour.min.sec"? Does the order matter (ie day before month)? Thanks.

Comment: ok. Just a little tip then: `show variables like 'datetime_format';` ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to sort them based on the date and time, you should probably think about using the TIMESTAMP. If you're using that field for record keeping, you can set the default value to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and MySQL will automatically insert this information for you.

Then, a simple query like the following would fetch all records and sort them by the TIMESTAMP field.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE something = 'matches' ORDER BY thetimestampfield DESC
```

Sample PHP code:

```
<?php
  // $c is a reference to mysql_connect() somewhere else in your code
  $q = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE something = 'matches' ORDER BY thetimestampfield DESC";
  $r = mysql_query($q, $c);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
    // do your thing
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can merge the two attributes since MySQL has `DateTime` data types. Since you have to attributes, you can stil sort the records by concatenating the two attributes and casting it to real `DateTime` value.

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`date`, ' ', `time`), '%m/%d/%Y') ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be more efficient to store your data as a timestamp or datetime and then use the date() function in PHP to format.

```
$var1 = date("m.d.Y", timestamp);
$var1 = date("h:i:s", timestamp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, in your MySQL table, create a new column, doesn't matter what the name is, with type DateTime or Timestamp, and you can set the default to CURRENT TIMESTAMP or something similar, I can't remember exactly what it's called, but it's easy to do in PHPMyAdmin. Then, you can just order by that. And the column will fill in automatically. Or you can just fill it in manually if you want. Then you just ORDER BY(`ColumnName`);

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you specify Mysql table field datatype as "DATETIME", and from php you can save data like `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` ?

And you can select the record and sort it by this date field either in descending or ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely try and leverage the database when you can.

Use an ORDER BY date_field, time_field at the end of your SELECT.

If the columns are actually strings then consider creating a new table and altering the column types so they are date and time respectively.  The STR_TO_DATE function can convert the string to a date.  If you like combine them into a single datetime column.  Might need a CONCAT or other string function if you want to do that.